# new version of Simulator does not match assistant app on devices

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Has anyone noticed that the Simulator in the Actions on Google Console has been updated and it no longer is an accurate simulation of the assistant app on devices?

They added a display tab but it seems to not show all the output. My application often includes 2 chat bubbles in one response and the new simulator only displays one even though the tts for both is heard in the audio.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Hope they don't remove the ability to add to responses. It would look terrible with only one line.

Comment: This seems to have been fixed now. I was ablt to get confirmation that you are still allowed 2 chat bubbles.